# Insert a variable as percentage into css using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm trying to make dynamic graphs so I need to use jquery to define the width of a div in css. Only problem I'm having is the width needs to be percent. Any ideas or thoughts would  be great. In the fiddle the inner div should be 93% and its displaying as 93px

```js
var TotalSites = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_ctl0_lblTotalSites").innerHTML;
var QuestionnairesSent = document.getElementById("ctl00_ContentBody_ctl0_lblQuestionnairesSent").innerHTML;
var Sent = QuestionnairesSent / TotalSites * 100;

$('.inner').css("width", Sent);
```

```css
.graph {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #666;
  float: left;
}

.inner {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graph">
  <div class="inner">
  </div>
</div>
<span id="ctl00_ContentBody_ctl0_lblTotalSites">15</span> /
<span id="ctl00_ContentBody_ctl0_lblQuestionnairesSent">14</span>
```

And here's my fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/SCATORY/pzzt390m/1/

Comment: Have you tried `$('.inner').css("width", Sent+'%');`?

Comment: That was it! tried it earlier without quotation. I feel like an idiot no. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help, @Jason. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.inner').css("width", Sent + "%");
```

CSS evaluates parses everything as strings, so you can set the width to 93. 93px, 93%, whatever. It just defaults to px when there's no suffix.

Answer (score 0):

just append a '%' sign to your css

```
 $('.inner').css("width", Sent + '%');
```

jsfiddle here

https://jsfiddle.net/pzzt390m/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$('.inner').width(Sent+'%');`